# Is this "the" method to get the pdf of a squared triangular distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1-x, &{0 \leq x \leq 1}\\
1+x, &{-1 \leq x < 0}\\
0  , &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

The pdf or cdf transformation $Y=X^2$ can be derived either by drawing triangles or possibly by doing a change of random variables with the corresponding Jacobian:

$$\rm dy=2x \, dx\implies \rm dx=\frac{\rm dy}{2 \sqrt y}$$

Since $x=\pm \sqrt y,$ considering $x=-\sqrt y$ the inverse transformation will map to $[-1,0]$ with pdf $1-x,$ and

$$f_Y(y^-) \rm dy=\frac{1+ \left(-\sqrt y \right)}{2 \sqrt y}\rm dy=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt y} -1\right)\rm dy.$$

If, on the other hand, $x=+\sqrt y,$ the inverse transformation will map to $[0,1]$ and

$$f_Y(y^+)\rm dy= \frac{1- \sqrt y }{2 \sqrt y}\rm dy=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt y} -1\right)\rm dy.$$

It makes sense to add these probabilities to extract the pdf:

$$f_Y(y)= \frac1{\sqrt y}-1$$

with support from $[0,1].$

Comment: It is "a" method - there are others

Comment: @Henry "The" as in the most expedient or most common - not as in 'the only' - the existence of many others was expected in asking the question. I also got the same answer drawing some triangles, etc. The question is how this is most usually taught in formal probability courses.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate, faster approach, using cumulative distribution functions.

$$F_{|X|}(y)=P(|X|<y)=\int_{-y}^y f_X(x)\,dx$$ when $y=[0,1].$ This is $$2\int_0^y (1-x)\,dx =2y-y^2.$$

So $$\begin{align}F_{X^2}(y)&=P(X^2<y)\\&=P(|X|<\sqrt y)\\&=F_{|X|}(\sqrt y)\\&=2\sqrt y-y
\end{align} 
$$ for $y\in [0,1].$

Then $f_{X^2}(y)$ is the derivative of $F_{X^2},$ $$\frac1{\sqrt y}-1.$$

Comment: I definitely saw two identical answers at the same time - but only one now

Comment: Probably a glitch. I quickly edited it after posting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: *Event faster:* don't bother integrating when you are immediately going to differentiate the result.  $$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathsf P(X^2\leq y)}{\mathrm d y} &= \dfrac{\mathrm d\mathsf P(-\surd y\leq X\leq y)}{\mathrm d y}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d( F_X(\surd y)-F_X(-\surd y))}{\mathrm d y}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{f_X(\surd y)+f_X(-\surd y)}{2\surd y}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{(1-\surd y)}{\surd y}\,\mathbf 1_{y\in[0..1)}\end{align}$$